# How to implement balance fanout in rxjava?

Tags: rx-java

Basically, we have a producer which produce a random number at a time and several consumers which sleep 1 second then print a number.

Every consumer is exclusive, every number can only have one receiver.
  This behavior is similar to JMS queue or BlockingQueue in java.

In akka stream, I can find

```
balance[T] – (1 input, N outputs) given an input element emits to one of its output ports.
```

But I can't find any built-in components in rxjava do the same job.
  Observable always broadcast message to all observers like `pub-sub` style. What should I do if I need `queue` style.

Am I miss anything?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you want to parallelize processing of elements?

Comment: Yes, I want to parallelize processing of elements. I can do this by multiple threads and blocking queue, but I wonder if I make this more elegantly.    
The producer is emitting events which fetched from database, and a bunch of  consumers doing time consuming jobs with these events. These consumers are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think the mental model you have doesn't really match what Rx is built around - think streams of many small operations, not messages between large-ish components.

I'd suggest a) a capped thread pool b) an RX scheduler around that and then c:

```
databaseSource
.fetchItems()
.flatMap(item -> 
   Obsevable.just(item)
   .observeOn(cappedThreadScheduler)
   .map(item -> longRunningOperation(item))
)
```

OTOH, you can do it like this too:

```
databaseSource
.fetchItems()
.flatMap(item -> 
   Obsevable.just(item)
   .observeOn(schedulers.io())
   .map(item -> longRunningOperation(item))
   , 16
)
```

To have at most 16 operations running in parallel.

Comment: hi, I update my code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701696/is-it-ok-to-transform-following-code-in-rxjava  , can you help in runnable code?