# Is it ok to transform following code in rxjava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

For example, I have following runnable java code.

It is about a producer and several parallel consumers. These consumers are running time consuming jobs, and they are running in parallel.

I wonder if this use case match rx-java, and how to rewrite it in rx-java.

```
public class DemoInJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
            int offset = 0;
            int limit = 10;
            while (true) {
                if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    if (offset < 100) {// there is 100 records in db
                        fetchDataFromDb(offset, limit).forEach(e -> queue.add(e));
                        offset = offset + limit;
                    } else {
                        done.set(true);
                        break; // no more data
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100l);// I don't like the idea of sleep, but it seems to be the simplest way.
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        List<Thread> consumers = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().map(c -> new Thread(() ->
        {
            while (true) {
                Integer i = queue.poll();
                if (i != null) {
                    longRunJob(i);
                } else {
                    if (done.get()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100l);// I don't like the idea of sleep, but it seems to be the simplest way.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());

        producer.start();
        consumers.forEach(c -> c.start());
    }

    private static List<Integer> fetchDataFromDb(int offset, int limit) {
        return IntStream.range(offset, offset + limit).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static void longRunJob(Integer i) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " long run job of " + i);
    }
}
```

the output is :

```
....
Thread-1 long run job of 7
Thread-1 long run job of 8
Thread-1 long run job of 9
Thread-4 long run job of 10
Thread-4 long run job of 16
Thread-10 long run job of 14
Thread-5 long run job of 15
Thread-8 long run job of 13
Thread-7 long run job of 12
Thread-9 long run job of 11
Thread-10 long run job of 19
Thread-4 long run job of 18
Thread-3 long run job of 17
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see... First, the code:

```
package rxtest;

import static io.reactivex.Flowable.generate;
import static io.reactivex.Flowable.just;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import io.reactivex.Emitter;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class Main {

    private static final Scheduler SCHEDULER = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

    private static class DatabaseProducer {
        private int offset = 0;
        private int limit = 100;

        void fetchDataFromDb(Emitter<List<Integer>> queue) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " fetching "+offset);
            queue.onNext(IntStream.range(offset, offset + limit).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            offset += limit;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generate(new DatabaseProducer()::fetchDataFromDb)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .concatMapIterable(list -> list, 1) // 1 call, no prefetch
        .flatMap(item -> 
                just(item)
                .doOnNext(i -> longRunJob(i))
                .subscribeOn(SCHEDULER)
                , 10) // don't subscribe to more than 10 at a time
        .take(1000)
        .blockingSubscribe();
    }

    private static void longRunJob(Integer i) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " long run job of " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class `DatabaseProducer` is simply the stateful producer of values, as it needs the current offset. It's not strictly necessary, as the `generate` call could have been replaced with

```
        generate(() -> 0, (offset,e) -> {
            e.onNext(IntStream.range(offset, offset + 100).boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            return offset + 100;
        }, e -> {});
```

But that's not nearly as readable.

Keep in mind that `cocatMap` and `flatMap` can and will pre-fetch and pre-subscribe to observables/flowables up to an implementations-dependent limit, even if there are no free threads to process them - they will simply get queued in the schedulers. The numbers on each call represent the limits that we want to have - 1 on the `concatMap` because we want to fetch from the database only if it's necessary (if you put here 2, you may over-read, but there will be less latency in the pipeline).

If you want to do Cpu-bound computation, then it's better to use `Schedulers.computation()`, as that is auto-configured to the number of CPUs of the system the JVM is running on, and you can use it from other parts of your codebase so that you don't overload the processor.

Comment: Don't forget  to accept the answer; it's how SO works.